# jQuery Right Mouse click context-menu plugins

Tags: jquery

I realize there are a lot out there but can people please recommend decent and lightweight jQuery Right Mouse click context-menu plugins.

URLs/demos would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm using this for a current project, only 4kb minified and no problems this far:
**[jQuery Context Menu Plugin](http://abeautifulsite.net/2008/09/jquery-context-menu-plugin/)** (abeautifulsite.net)

Direct demo page: [Here](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-contextMenu/demo/)

Comment: the demo is here now http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-contextMenu/demo/

Comment: BTW, the plugin seemed worked for me ONLY after I commented out instances of $(document).unbind('click'). They were messing up other click handlers.

Comment: project page's link is broken

Comment: I used that plugins, but the only problem that I found with it, is that it doesn't support overflow, I tried to open the context-menu next to a border, and it's cutting the menu.

Answer (score 5):

here is the jQuery code to disable "regular" context menu :

```
$(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e){ return false; });
```

It's usefull when you want to use your own context menu but dont't what to show the navigator's context menu...

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqueryContextMenu

Demo
http://www.trendskitchens.co.nz/jquery/contextmenu/

There are plenty available in the net.. google it.

Answer (score 0):

I like this one:

http://abeautifulsite.net/2008/09/jquery-context-menu-plugin/

there is a right-click plugin on that side as well. Note, that Opera does not support context-menus

Answer (score 0):

You can use this jQuery plugin developed by me. It's called [Audero Context Menu](https://github.com/AurelioDeRosa/Audero-Context-Menu).